# AntivirusProduct remove specific

Tags: powershell

Good Morning,

We recently changed antivirus and I keep finding the old software in the registry keys. Is there any way to remove the single output where displayedName is like AntivirusNAME?

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\SecurityCenter2 -ClassName AntivirusProduct
displayName              : AntivirusNAME
instanceGuid             : {8E0623B8-CF1C-DFFE-CEA3-AA41BDAAAAAA}
pathToSignedProductExe   : 
pathToSignedReportingExe : 
productState             : 327680
timestamp                : Thu, 11 Mar 2021 12:06:08 GMT
PSComputerName           :

displayName              : AntivirusNAME2
instanceGuid             : {8E0623B8-CF1C-DFFE-CEA3-AA41BDAAAABB}
pathToSignedProductExe   : 
pathToSignedReportingExe : 
productState             : 327680
timestamp                : Thu, 11 Mar 2021 12:06:08 GMT
PSComputerName           :

displayName              : AntivirusNAME3
instanceGuid             : {8E0623B8-CF1C-DFFE-CEA3-AA41BDAAAACC}
pathToSignedProductExe   : 
pathToSignedReportingExe : 
productState             : 327680
timestamp                : Thu, 11 Mar 2021 12:06:08 GMT
PSComputerName           :
```

if I use this string I eliminate everything

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\SecurityCenter2 -Class AntiVirusProduct | ForEach-Object{$_.Delete()}
```

Comment: Yes, `Remove-Ciminstance`. I'm not too good with WQL filtering, so I could suggest piping to a `Where-Object -eq 'AntivirusNAME'`.